Construction of primitive additive character modulo an integral ideal
Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathfrak{O}$ be its ring of integers. Let $\mathfrak{b}$ be an integral ideal of $K$. I want to construct a additive character modulo the integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ which is primitive.
According to the book Elementary and Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers , We can choose any element $a$ in the fractional ideal $\mathfrak{b}^{-1}\mathfrak{d}^{-1}$. Then the map
$$e(x)=e^{2 \pi i \operatorname{Tr}(ax)}$$ is a primitive character modulo $\mathfrak{b}$. Since $a \in K$ ,it can be written as $a=\frac{\beta}{\gamma}$, where $\beta, \gamma \in \mathfrak{O}$. I am interested to know more about this. I am curious to know what kind of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ will work?
In the standard case, we can consider the map
$$e(x)=e^{2 \pi i \operatorname{Tr}(\frac{k x}{ n })}$$
And here we are choosing $\beta$ such that $(\beta,n)=1$ and $\gamma=n$. In fact this gives are the primitive characters modulo $n$, that is modulo the integral ideal $(n)$
Thank You in Advance.

It is not true that $e(x)$ is primitive mod $\mathfrak b$ when $a$ is arbitrary in $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$: try $a = 0$. And although each element of $K$ is a ratio of elements in $\mathfrak O$, when $h(K) > 1$ it is not generally possible to write such a ratio in reduced form, so you can't expect there to be some "nice" expression of $a$ as a ratio using elements $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in $\mathfrak O$. Just deal with $a$ directly.

@KCd, They have constructed such a primitive character here at https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2385 , but I am not able to understand this. Thing is there are choosing "some" prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_1$ and some $\alpha \in \mathfrak{o}$ which works for us. This is getting very difficult as I know the existence only, but have no information over the choosen elements. Would you be able to suggest something?

I wrote an answer below explaining why there are primitive additive characters. To construct one in the way you described the additive characters in your question amounts to constructing an $a$ that generates $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ as an $\mathfrak O$-module.

It's not clear whether you understand how to show all the characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ are $x \bmod \mathfrak b \mapsto e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(xy)}$ for some $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$,
where ${\rm Tr} := {\rm Tr}_{K/\mathbf Q}$,
so I want to go over this first, leading up to Theorem 1 below. Then I'll discuss primitive characters.
The fractional ideal $\mathfrak d^{-1}$, which always contains $\mathfrak O$,  is the $\mathbf Z$-dual of $\mathfrak O$ with respect to the trace pairing on $K$:
$$
\mathfrak d^{-1} = \{t \in K : {\rm Tr}(t\mathfrak O) \subset \mathbf Z\}. 
$$
In particular, ${\rm Tr}(\mathfrak d^{-1}) \subset \mathbf Z$. Using $\mathfrak d^{-1}$, we'll parametrize the characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ in a way that generalizes the parametrization of the characters of $\mathbf Z/b\mathbf Z$ as $\{x \bmod b \mapsto e^{2\pi irx} : r \in (1/b)\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z\}$. (When $K = \mathbf Q$, $\mathfrak d = (1) = \mathbf Z$, so we don't easily see the role of the different ideal in the description of characters of the simplest case $\mathbf Z/b\mathbf Z$.)
When $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$, define the character $\chi_y : \mathfrak O/\mathfrak b \to S^1$ by $\chi_y(x \bmod \mathfrak b) = e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(xy)}$.  The function $\chi_y$ on $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is well-defined since when $x \equiv x' \bmod \mathfrak b$ in $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ we have $x, x' \in \mathfrak O$ and
$$
x - x' \in \mathfrak b \Rightarrow (x-x')y \in \mathfrak b\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1} = \mathfrak d^{-1} \Rightarrow {\rm Tr}((x-x')y) \in \mathbf Z \Rightarrow e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}((x-x')y)} = 1,
$$
so $e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(xy)} = e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(x'y)}$ and that proves well-definedness of $\chi_y$. Easily $\chi_y$ is a character  on $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ (group homomorphism $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b \to S^1$).  It is the trivial character if and only if its only value on $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is $1$, which is equivalent to saying ${\rm Tr}(\mathfrak O y) \subset \mathbf Z$, which is equivalent to $y \in \mathfrak d^{-1}$.
Now we'll show all characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ look like $\chi_y$ for some $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$.
Check the map $y \mapsto \chi_y$ from $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$ to the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is a group homomorphism. Then by what we showed above, the kernel of $y \mapsto \chi_y$ is $\mathfrak d^{-1}$. (We have $\mathfrak d^{-1} \subset \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$ because that containment is the same as $\mathfrak b \subset \mathfrak O$ and that last containment holds since $\mathfrak b$ is a nonzero ideal in $\mathfrak O$.) Thus we have an injective group homomorphism from $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ to the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ by $\overline{y} \mapsto \chi_y$. It is surjective because the finite abelian groups
$\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ and the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ have the same size:
(1) $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as $\mathfrak O$-modules since that is a special case of $I/J \cong \mathfrak O/JI^{-1}$ for all fractional $\mathfrak O$-ideals $I$ and $J$ in $K$, and thus $|\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}| = |\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b| = {\rm N}(\mathfrak b)$.
Note: while the $\mathfrak O$-modules $I/J$ and $\mathfrak O/JI^{-1}$ are isomorphic, they are not canonically isomorphic in general.
(2) $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is a finite abelian group, so its character group has size $|\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b|$.
That proves the injective group homomorphism $\overline{y} \mapsto \chi_y$ from $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ to the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is surjective and thus is an isomorphism. In other words, we have proved the following theorem.
Theorem 1. Each character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ has the form $\chi_y(x \bmod \mathfrak b) := e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(xy)}$ for $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$ and $y$ is uniquely determined modulo $\mathfrak d^{-1}$ by $\chi_y$. Thus the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ as finite abelian groups.
Now we turn to primitive characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$. When $\mathfrak c \mid \mathfrak b$, there is a natural reduction map $r_{\mathfrak b,\mathfrak c} \colon \mathfrak O/\mathfrak b \to \mathfrak O/\mathfrak c$, and composition of this map with any character of
$\mathfrak O/\mathfrak c$ creates a character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$. A character $\chi$ of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is called primitive when
$\chi$ does not come from a character modulo a proper factor of $\mathfrak b$ in that way:  there is no proper ideal factor $\mathfrak c$ of $\mathfrak b$ and character $\psi$ of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak c$ such that $\chi = \psi \circ r_{\mathfrak b,\mathfrak c}$.  Do primitive characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ exist?  It is not obvious! Concretely,
we already know characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ look like $\chi_y$ where $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$ and $y$ matters modulo $\mathfrak d^{-1}$. When we write
a character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as $\chi_y$, the next theorem describes primitivity of the character in terms of $y$, or rather in terms of $\overline{y}$ in $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$.
Theorem 2. When $\overline{y} \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$, the character $\chi_y$ of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is  primitive if and only if $\mathfrak O \overline{y} = \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$, i.e., $\overline y$ does not generate a proper $\mathfrak O$-submodule.
Proof.  Exercise.  QED
Remark.  For $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$, the condition $\mathfrak O \overline{y} = \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ is equivalent to $y\mathfrak b\mathfrak d + \mathfrak b = \mathfrak O$.
By Theorem 2, the existence of primitive characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is the same as $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ having a generator as an $\mathfrak O$-module: it has to be a cyclic $\mathfrak O$-module.  Why is $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ a cyclic $\mathfrak O$-module? Recall we saw earlier that $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1} \cong \mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as $\mathfrak O$-modules since this is a special case of $I/J \cong \mathfrak O/JI^{-1}$ where $I$ and $J$ are fractional ideals. And $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as an $\mathfrak O$-module is obviously cyclic since it has generator $1$. Thus $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ is a cyclic $\mathfrak O$-module. So $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ does have a primitive character, namely $\chi_y$ where $\overline{y}$ in $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ is an $\mathfrak O$-module generator.
But watch out: $I/J$ and $\mathfrak O/JI^{-1}$ usually are not canonically isomorphic as $\mathfrak O$-modules (or even as abelian groups). Thus the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ always has a primitive character but it usually does not have a canonical primitive character.
There is another point of view on primitive characters, based on thinking  about the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ not only as an abelian group, but as an $\mathfrak O$-module. Make the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ into an $\mathfrak O$-module by "interior multiplication": for $\alpha \in \mathfrak O$ and $\chi$ a character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$, set $(\alpha \chi)(x \bmod \mathfrak b) := \chi(\alpha x \bmod \mathfrak b)$). That the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ becomes
an $\mathfrak O$-module in this way amounts to checking for all $\alpha, \alpha' \in \mathfrak O$ and characters $\chi, \chi'$ that
$$
(\alpha + \alpha')\chi \stackrel{?}{=} (\alpha\chi)(\alpha'\chi), \ \ \
\alpha(\chi \chi') \stackrel{?}{=} (\alpha\chi)(\alpha\chi') 
$$
in the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ (where the group law is pointwise multiplication of characters). Evaluate both sides of each equation at each $x \bmod \mathfrak b$ in $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$:
(1) the first equation at $x \bmod \mathfrak b$ turns into $\chi((\alpha +\alpha')x) \stackrel{?}{=} \chi(\alpha x)\chi(\alpha'x)$, which is valid by $\chi$ being a character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$,
(2) the second equation at $x \bmod \mathfrak b$ turns into $\chi(\alpha x)\chi'(\alpha x) \stackrel{?}{=} (\alpha \chi)(x)(\alpha \chi')(x)$, which is valid by the definition of the $\mathfrak O$-module structure on the characters of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$.  $\checkmark$
We already saw that the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ as abelian groups.  Since $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$  is a quotient of two $\mathfrak O$-modules, it is an $\mathfrak O$-module in a natural way. We can now compare  the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ and $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ as
$\mathfrak O$-modules, not just as abelian groups.  Here is the comparison.
Theorem 3.  The map $\overline{y} \mapsto \chi_y$ from $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ to the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is an $\mathfrak O$-module isomorphism.
Proof.  By Theorem 1 this map is an isomorphism of abelian groups, so it remains to show it is $\mathfrak O$-linear: for each $\alpha \in \mathfrak O$ and $y \in \mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}$, we want to check
$$
\chi_{\alpha y} \stackrel{?}{=} \alpha\chi_y
$$
in the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$. Evaluate both sides of this equation at each $x \bmod \mathfrak b$ in $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$: the left side becomes $e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(x(\alpha y))}$ and the right side becomes $\chi_y(\alpha x)$, which is $e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}((\alpha x)y)}$. These two numbers are equal, so we are done. QED
By Theorem 3, the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ as $\mathfrak O$-modules. The quotient $\mathfrak O$-module $\mathfrak b^{-1}\mathfrak d^{-1}/\mathfrak d^{-1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as  $\mathfrak O$-modules, but usually not canonically, so the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as $\mathfrak O$-modules, but usually not canonically. By Theorems 2 and 3, generators of the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ are the primitive characters.
Theorem 4.  When $\chi$ is a primitive character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$, each character of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is $x \bmod \mathfrak b \mapsto \chi(\alpha x)$ where $\alpha \in \mathfrak O$ is uniquely determined modulo $\mathfrak b$, and this character is primitive if and only if $\alpha \bmod \mathfrak b$ is a unit in $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$.
Proof.  That $\chi$ is primitive is equivalent to saying $\chi$ is a generator of the character group of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ as an $\mathfrak O$-module. This character group as an $\mathfrak O$-module is (non-canonically) isomorphic to $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$. When $M$ is an $\mathfrak O$-module that is  isomorphic to $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ and $m$ is a generator of $M$, each element of $M$ is $\alpha m$ where $\alpha \in \mathfrak O$ is uniquely determined modulo $\mathfrak b$, and $\alpha m$ is a generator of $M$ if and only if $\alpha \bmod \mathfrak b$ is a unit in $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$.  That proves the theorem since
the character $\alpha\chi$ of $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ is, using the $\mathfrak O$-module structure of the characters, the same as the function $x \bmod \mathfrak b \mapsto \chi(\alpha x)$.  QED

Also apart from the definition of $\mathfrak{d}^{-1}=\hat{\mathfrak{O}}$, I do not know why this different ideal is important. I read this expository article https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf , but all I get is, there are finitely many ramified primes(precisely those which divide the different, but I fail to see its importance.

Yeah, I've seen that link too. :) The different ideal is subtle. If all you got out of that link is the application to ramified primes then you did not read it carefully enough, especially the discussion of $\mathbf Z$-duals with respect to the trace pairing earlier, which is motivated by dual lattics in $\mathbf R^n$. That is what you really need to master, since it is really the inverse of $\mathfrak d$ in its role as the $\mathbf Z$-dual of $\mathfrak O$ that you need to use. The whole "prime factors of $\mathfrak d$ are ramified primes" business is irrelevant.

I am trying to relate this construction with the standard primitive character modulo $n$, that is the ideal $(n)$. Your theorem says that $\chi(x)=e^{2\pi i Tr(\alpha x}$ is a primitive character if and only if $\alpha$ is a unit modulo $\frac{\mathfrak{O}}{\mathfrak{b}}$, but If I consider $e^{2 \pi i \frac{1}{p}}$, then I am not understanding how $\frac{1}{p}$ is a unit in $\frac{\mathfrak{O}}{\mathfrak{b}}$

The number $e^{2\pi i/p}$ is not a function, so I don't know what the part of your comment after "but" means. When describing an additive character, please specify the domain as well as what the character is.

I apologize for the typing mistake. I meant $\chi(a)=e^{\frac{2 \pi i k a }{n} }$ is a primitive additive character modulo $(n)$ whenever $(k,n)=1$. In this case I wanted to understand how $k/n$ is a unit

The theorem does not say $k/n$ is a unit. It is $\chi(x) = e^{2\pi ix/n}$ that is an  additive character on $\mathbf Z/(n)$ such that every additive character on $\mathbf Z/(n)$ is $\chi(kx) = e^{2\pi ikx/n}$ for some integer $k$, and $x \bmod n \mapsto \chi(kx)$  is primitive if and only if $k\bmod n$ is a unit.  The function $x \mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ on $\mathbf Z$ and the function $x\mapsto e^{2\pi i{\rm Tr}(x)}$ on $\mathfrak O$ are both identically $1$ and thus are boring. Make sure you have a reasonable definition of $\chi$ on $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak b$ before looking at $\chi(\alpha x)$.

Alright, I think it meant to say that, given a fixed primitive character $\chi_0$ modulo an integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}$, then as $\beta$ runs through the elements of $(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{b})^*$, the function $\chi(\beta . )$ gives primitive characters modulo $\mathfrak{b}$

Sure, that's true. Do you still have a question?

Not many questions, I tried reading the construction of primitive character modulo an integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ at https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2385 . I would love to discuss more about the construction in the reference. I will probably write another post and write all the details, along with any doubts I have

Try running through the construction of a primitive additive character by the  article’s method in the case when $\mathfrak O = \mathbf Z$ and $\mathfrak b = m\mathbf Z$ to compare what you get with the simple construction of $\chi(x) = e^{2\pi ix/m}$.
